# Какое влияние будет оказываться на основную машину при запуске вредоносного ПО в контейнере/ в WSL2?

Tags: docker, виртуальная-машина, wsl2

Если запусить вредоносное ПО на VM это не повлияет на мой ПК. Эту виртуалку можно будет просто удалит и создать новую.  Какое влияние будет оказываться на основную машину при запуске вредоносного ПО в контейнере/ в WSL?

Comment: WSL имеет доступ ко всему диску винды, по умолчанию, так что WSL - это не контейнер )))   это контейнер без крышки ))))